# NReal glasses with Samsung S10 - getting a black screen / "Security policy prevents use of Camera"

Tags: nreal

I installed the Nebula app (Android, Samsung S10) and connected glasses, clicked the MR Space option. I am getting "Mode switch completed" message, and then a black screen.
Whenever I am trying to click the phones camera, I am getting "Security policy prevents use of Camera". It starts only after I connect the glasses to the device.

Any idea?
Thanks.